# cocoa: NSTableview refresh after NSProgressIndicator animating

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsprogressindicator

My cocoa app needs to fetch data from network and then shows content in the table view. So I add a spinning style of `NSProgressIndicator` to animate when the data is downloading. After that the animation of `NSProgressIndicator` stops and reloads the `NSTableView`. The strange thing is after the table view reloading, the content shown is not updated. Then If you scroll the table view, the content starts to show,just like:
[image]
(the small rectangle above is the frame for the `NSProgressIndicator`)

Below is my code:

```
- (void)loadOperationData
{   
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self _showIndicator];
    });

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getOperationLogProcess) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)_showIndicator
{
    if (indicator == nil) 
    {
        indicator = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] init];
        [indicator setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];
        [indicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:NO];// I tried to comment this, but no use
        int width = 30;
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width);
        NSRect selfRect = [_coverView frame];
        rect.origin.x = selfRect.size.width/2 - width/2;
        rect.origin.y = selfRect.size.height/2 - width/2;
        indicator.frame = rect;
        [_coverView addSubview:indicator];
    }
    
    [indicator setHidden:NO];
    [indicator startAnimation:self];
}

-(void)getOperationLogProcess{
    
    NSDictionary *tempResutDic = [WebServiceManager getOperationLog];//using synchronous ASIHttpRequest to download data
    if ([[tempResutDic objectForKey:@"resultCode"] intValue]==100) {
        self.operationLogArray = [tempResutDic objectForKey:@"items"];
        
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];//refresh UI in main thread
    }
}

-(void)reloadTableview
{
    [indicator stopAnimation:self];
    [indicator setHidden:YES];
    [operationlogTable setEnabled:YES];
    
    if ([_coverView isHidden])
    {
        return;
    }
    
    self.lastUpdateDate = [NSDate date];
    
    [operationlogTable reloadData];
}
```

The  `-(void)loadOperationData` is called by the mouse click event. And The reason why I put the  `-(void)_showIndicator` in a dispatch block is that the indicator can't be shown. I tried a lot and finally chose it.

I guess the problem ties closely to the way of showing indicator because If I commented the code about the indicator, the problem dismissed.

I really need the indicator to let user know they are waiting.So Please help me how to correctly use NSProgressIndicator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by the multithread.

In`- (void)loadOperationData` I use main block to show progress indicator and create a thread to fetch data in background. The block is run asynchronously and sometimes is after the  `-(void)reloadTableview`.

Finally, I keep `- (void)loadOperationData` is called in main thread and put the `- (void)_showIndicator` out of the block. Then it is fixed.